# Finding PassengerRuby from the Application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I am using **rvm - passenger - apache** combination. For different apps i have the `PassengerRuby` specified in the host file.

Like this:

App1.conf

```
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/wrappers/ruby
```

App2.conf

```
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/wrappers/ruby
```

I want to find from the application with which Ruby  it's Running. So that i can display to the user.

How can i do that from the application itself?

Comment: Isn't RUBY_VERSION enough?

Comment: wow, @VictorMoroz it worked! I over thought about it .. Thanks, Can you please reply with same as the Answer also. So that i can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RUBY_VERSION` indicates the version of the Ruby interpreter. There is also `RUBY_PATCHLEVEL` if you need more information.